# p:dataExporter csv decimal column not between quotation marks

Tags: jsf, csv, primefaces

I have a `<p:dataExporter>` that produces a CSV file. 
Unfortunately, the decimal column is not between quotation marks. This gives me some problems as my decimal separator is a comma.

How could I fix it? Maybe is it possible to put quotation marks for decimal values or change the CSV separator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comma as decimal separator is typical European. In turn, European CSV formats generally use a semicolon as CSV separator. That should also solve this problem.

The `<p:dataExporter>`, however, doesn't support changing the CSV separator via some tag attribute. The comma is hardcoded in PrimeFaces [`CSVExporter` source code](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/export/CSVExporter.java) instead of parameterized. This is also reported as [issue 4714](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4714) which is currently accepted but still open for more than a year. The issue also mentions [Lapis JSF exporter](https://github.com/rdicroce/jsfexporter) as an alternative solution for data exporting.

An quick workaround would be to copypaste the original [`CSVExporter` source code file](https://primefaces.googlecode.com/svn/primefaces/trunk/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/export/CSVExporter.java) into your WAR, maintaining the package structure, and edit it to replace all occurrences of `writer.write(",");` by `writer.write(";");`. When multiple classes with same FQN are found in both WAR and a JAR in WAR's `/WEB-INF/lib`, the one in WAR will get precedence in classloading and be used instead.